# Has Wonder Woman previously been described as a demigod?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe, justice-league, wonder-woman

In [Justice League Unlimited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League_Unlimited), Hades claims to be Wonder Woman’s father. And in New 52, Zeus is her father. Both of these would make her a demigoddess.

In any previous DC comic, was she described as a demigoddess? Or is this a recent addition to her story?

Comment: Yes, she is Demigod by definition. Which type of treatment are you looking for?

Comment: @SachinShekhar Did she ever mentioned as Demigod in comics?

Comment: @SachinShekhar - I think question is, was she a Demigod before New 52 reboot.

Comment: Sorry to be picky but in the Wonder Woman movie and I assume Justice League Unlimited, she is a full blown goddess, and Gal Gadot has confirmed this in interviews. She would be a Demigod if she was born of Queen Hippolyta, but Hippolyta is effectively her foster mother as she was given life by Zeus.

Comment: @KevH something created and given power by a good isn't automatically a god. Also, not sure about the comics, but later in the movie I thought they made it pretty clear that Zeus got it on with Hippolyta, though perhaps that's just my interpretation since that's how Zeus rolls in just about every Greek myth of him.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No she wasn't always a demigod nor stated to be...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Woman

Golden Age she was simply a member of a tribe of Amazon Women...

Silver Age she was was mortal but got her powers through blessings of the gods.

Bronze Age she was molded from clay...

Now in Modern Age she was molded from clay and given powers from different gods..

> Various deities and concepts from Greek mythology were blended and
>   incorporated into Wonder Woman's stories and origin. Diana was formed
>   out of clay of the shores of Themyscira by Hippolyta, who wished for a
>   child; the clay figure was then brought to life by the Greek deities.
>   The Gods then blessed and granted her unique powers and abilities –
>   beauty from Aphrodite, strength from Demeter, wisdom from Athena,
>   speed and flight from Hermes, Eyes of the Hunter and unity with beasts
>   from Artemis and sisterhood with fire and the ability to discern the
>   truth from Hestia.

She eventually got killed and became a god...

> The demon Neron engaged Diana in battle and managed to kill her.
>   The Olympian Gods granted Diana divinity and the role of the Goddess
>   of Truth who started to reside in Olympus; her mother Hippolyta then
>   assumed the role of Wonder Woman and wore her own different
>   incarnation of the costume.

In New 52 Zeus is her father so that does make her a demigod.

As well as your mention of Justice League Unlimited where Hades claims to be her father, although I can't find anywhere saying that he was telling the truth...

So overall Wonder Woman was never really a demigod until recently.

Answer (score 4):

From http://www.newsarama.com/8485-wonder-woman-gets-a-new-52-origin-parent-in-november.html:

> As Monday on DC's official publicity blog The Source, in the current continuity, Wonder Woman's mother is Hippolyta and father is Zeus. **This is a significant change to the character's history, who traditionally has never had a father figure and was said to be formed from mystical clay.**

This is confirmed by [Hippolyta Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippolyta_%28DC_Comics%29) and [Wonder Woman's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Woman) - before New 52 there was no father. I won't bother copy/pasting actual origin stories from Wikipedia.

---

Interestingly enough, OUTSIDE comics continuity, Wonder Woman's mother, [Hippolyta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippolyta), was herself a Demigoddess (daughter of Ares), so her child would have been a quarter-Olympian regardless of the father. But as far as I was able to find, that Greek Mythology fact was never present in DC comics.

Comment: Not necessarily considering that in Modern Age Hippolyta made a clay child and then the Greek Gods gave life to it... Did the gods actually make Diana have dna of her mother?

Comment: If they didn't and just made the clay person alive through magic, whose to say that she has no actual relation to Hippolyta other than the fact that she raised Wonder Woman.